# Qual è il senso di "svelto" in questo brano?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, adjectives

Nella commedia *Morte accidentale di un anarchico* di Dario Fo ho letto:

> Per un operaio alla catena o alla trancia dopo i cinquant’anni è finita: combina ritardi, incidenti, è da
>   scartare! Il minatore a quarantacinque anni ha la silicosi... via, scartato, licenziato, **svelto**, prima che scatti
>   la pensione!

Non capisco bene il senso di questo "svelto" nella frase precedente. Quello che ho trovato nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/svelto/) che mi è sembrato più adatto al testo è

> In formule esclam., esortando a operare sollecitamente: *fa’ svelto!, entra s.!, salta s.!* (espressioni in cui assume quasi uso avverbiale); e, assol., *svelto!, su svelto!; svelti, ragazzi!; svelto! vieni a darmi una mano*.

Tuttavia, non sono sicura che questo sia il significato: se invita sollecitamente il minatore a lasciare il suo lavoro prima di andare in pensione?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'invito non è al minatore, ma al datore di lavoro. Sta sollecitando il proprietario a licenziare rapidamente il dipendente prima che si qualifichi per la pensione per invalidità dovuta alla silicosi (a cui presumo il datore di lavoro debba contribuire, dato che si tratta di una malattia causata dalle condizioni di lavoro).